# Is there any way to update card billing data like name, address, etc. in stripe-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a stripe form in my UI which creates user payment method. However I want to give the user option to update their billing address without changing the card. Is there any way to update billing data like name, address, etc. in stripe-js from the frontend? The same way as creating a card/payment method.

Comment: have you tried
https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_methods/update?lang=node#update_payment_method-billing_details